# C++11: intptr_t/int_ptr_t, intmax_t/int_max_t?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm doing a bit of reading on c++11 and I've noticed a couple things about int type names. Right now, apparently the spec is only available by paying for it but there is an early draft from February available at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf

However I noticed on a website which is cited on the c++11 wikipedia page, en.cppreference.com, a discrepency in a couple of the standard integer types.

The page at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer mentions various fixed-width integer types, and also `int_max_t` and `int_ptr_t`. However the spec linked above uses `intmax_t` and `intptr_t` (without the middle underscore) which I am used to and which already exists in, for example, MS's `crtdefs.h`, and boost's `cstdint.hpp`. Is this likely just a typo on the website, did this change in the spec since the February draft?

**Edit** Removed stuff about the header files, it was irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I figured that was probably the case. I went ahead and submitted an edit to that page on cppreference.com, hopefully it sticks. :)

Comment: You're welcome to edit more! That website is a community effort and there is plenty that's still missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's just a typo on the website. From the FDIS, §18.4.1 (`Header <cstdint> synopsis`):

> `namespace std {`
>        ...
>      `typedef` *signed integer type* `intmax_t;`
>      `typedef` *signed integer type* `intptr_t; //`*optional*
>        ...
>      `typedef` *unsigned integer type* `uintmax_t;`
>      `typedef` *unsigned integer type* `uintptr_t; //`*optional*
>   `} //`*namespace std*