# intmax_t Data Type in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++11: intptr_t/int_ptr_t, intmax_t/int_max_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895420/c11-intptr-t-int-ptr-t-intmax-t-int-max-t)

I am using C platform on Visual Studio. I want to know that intmax_t datatype is only used for Linux based programming or It is supported by C language(ANSI Language) as well.

Comment: Question very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7895420/841108

Comment: Did you google for `intmax_t`? It is certainly not Linux specific, and it is in C99 and later standards of C (with `<stdint.h>` header)!

Comment: Note that the phrase "ANSI C" typically means C89.  Microsoft does not support C99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, both `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` are parts of C99, but *some* compilers actually need to be shimmed with something like [this](http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h) (or [this](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/pstdint.h)) to use them. Quoting the [main page](https://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/) of the first link here:

> This project fills the absence of `stdint.h` and `inttypes.h` in Microsoft
>   Visual Studio. This files were standartized by ISO/IEC as a part of
>   C99 standard library. If you want to compile or use C99 compliant
>   project with Microsoft Visual Studio, you will likely find that you're
>   missing these headers.